# Bootstrap with rails: Align a dropup with other element in a footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, footer

I'm trying to align the following as a footer, but the dropup doesn't align with the rest:

```
<footer class="footer">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">

  <div class="pull-left">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li><%= link_to 'Privacy', privacy_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to 'Contact', contact_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to 'Help', help_path %></li>
      </ul>

    <div class="dropup">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" href="#" style="text-decoration: none !important;"><%= t 'footer_languages' %><span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
           <li><%= link_to_unless_current "English", locale: "en" %></li>
           <li><%= link_to_unless_current "German", locale: "de" %></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

      <ul class="social-network social-circle pull-right">
       <li><a href="#" class="icoFacebook" title="Facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="icoTwitter" title="Twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="icoGoogle" title="Google +"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</footer>

.footer
  position: absolute
  bottom: 0
  width: 100%
  height: 40px
```

and here is the image:
[image]
Don't mind the color difference, its from the crop I did!

Any ideas on how to align everything??

**Upadte 1**

According to @Kundan Kumar Mourya answer if get these results now:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[click here to check the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2JmJ.png)

```html
<footer class="footer">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
 

  <div class="col-sm-4 pull-left">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li>'Privacy', privacy_path</li>
        <li>link_to 'Contact', contact_path</li>
        <li>link_to 'Help', help_path</li>
      </ul>
      </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4 dropup">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" href="#" style="text-decoration: none !important;"> 'footer_languages'<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
           <li> link_to_unless_current "English", locale: </li>
           <li>link_to_unless_current "German", locale: </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    <ul class="social-network social-circle pull-right">
       <li><a href="#" class="icoFacebook" title="Facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook">Facebook</i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="icoTwitter" title="Twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter">Facebook</i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="icoGoogle" title="Google +"><i class="fa fa-google-plus">Facebook</i></a></li>
     </ul>
  </div>


</div>
</div>
</footer>
```

i fix it, have look but i change some div and class

Comment: I updated my question it with a new pic! I made the changes according to your answer and the I'm getting the results of the pic.

Comment: i understand what you are try to say  https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/35gvb

Comment: please add in your code and remove the only text whatever i add in that code, just like i add ( fa ga fa ) in the place on social icon

Comment: I removed all of the ruby on rails links and I only added text... but still the same results

Comment: i want the dropup to be on the left hand side along with rest... and the social media on the right hand side. And I want all of the elements to be aligned!

Comment: i that there is any bug in your file of css or  html so that why it's not working properly

Comment: Add this in your css file


.nav li{
    padding:0 10px ;
}
.social-network li{
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0 10px ;
}
.footer [class^='col-sm']{
    margin:10px 0;
   vertical-align:middle;
}